# Plotting cobweb diagram

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a cobweb diagram of f(x)=r*x*(1-x), where r = 3. I am currently trying to use the following code:

```
function cobweb(f,a,b,x0,x1,N)
x(1)=0.2; % plot orbit starting at x0
for i=1:100
    x(i+1)= 3*x(i)*(x(i)+1);
    plot([x(i),x(i)],[x(i),x(i+1)]);
    hold on
    plot([x(i),x(i+1)],[x(i+1),x(i+1)]);
    hold on
end
hold off
```

But the resulting plot I get is completely wrong!

Comment: your function does not seem to use any of its arguments? What is your expected result?

Comment: also, shouldn't this line `x(i+1)= 3*x(i)*(x(i)+1);` be `x(i+1)= 3*x(i)*(1-x(i));`? That gives a converging trajectory ...

Comment: @zeeMonkeez Thank you!! I didn't see that mistake!